# Google Maps v3 OK on Android 2.2 device, not showing on Android 4.2

Tags: android, google-maps, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3, cordova

**///////// UPDATE ////////**

OK, after several days of troubleshooting I have managed to get the map displaying properly on both Android devices.

Turns out I needed to do the following together:

- use a different src URL for google maps in my index.html which is this one: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false`
- I needed to allow access to everything so in my config.xml:
  `<access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>`

Now the main issue is that I dont want to whitelist everything but if I allow the usual suspects of *.google.com, *.googleapis.com, *.gstatic.com etc I get some weird behaviours **on the Android 4.2.2 device only** - for example, the bottom of the map wont display fully (missing last row of tiles) if I use https for the src URL and markers will not show AT ALL.
However by whitelisting everything, everything works OK again.

I think I will start anew thread concerning the whitelisting domains and the issues I'm having because I cant seem to find anything about it.

**//////// ORIGINAL QUESTION ////////**

I am building an app with phonegap and jquery mobile.
On one of the pages I just want to display a map with markers, etc.

However the issue I am now facing is this:

- Map displays OK on Chrome on Desktop PC
- Map displays OK on real Android Device (HTC Desire) running android 2.2.2
- Map fails to display at all on real Android Device (Sony Xperia Z1) on Android 4.2.2

UPDATE: I have also tested on HTC One running 4.2.2 - same issue, map not displaying.

**HTML**

```
<div data-role="page" id="mappage">
<div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
    <h3>
        Map
    </h3>
</div>

<div data-role="content" id="content">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="height:100%"></div>
</div>

<div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <h3>&nbsp;

    </h3>
</div>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#mappage',function(){ 

BuildMap( 50.725,-3.528,50.726,-3.526 );

function BuildMap( lat_shop, long_shop, lat_phone, long_phone ){

    var minZoomLevel = 16;

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
      zoom: minZoomLevel,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng( lat_shop, long_shop ),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var marker_shop = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng( lat_shop, long_shop ),
      map: map
    });

    var marker_phone = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng( lat_phone, long_phone ),
      map: map
    });

}
```

});

**CSS:**

```
#content {
padding: 0;
position : absolute !important; 
top : 40px !important;  
right : 0; 
bottom : 40px !important;  
left : 0 !important;
```

}

Other bits that might help:

I have a single button that links to the page to show the map. ON desktop and 2.2.2 it works OK. On 4.2.2 it highlighted the button but did not change the page. I'm guessing that because the code is running in the 'pageinit', it hit a problem and did not go any further.

I change the 'pageinit' to 'pageshow' - no difference exactly the same issue - desktop and android 2 OK, android 4.2.2. nothing just a blank page (it obviously managed to change the page this time).

Comment: Does it still happen if you set a width on `map_canvas` as well?

Comment: unfortunately yes I still have the same issue of non-display on Android 4.2.2

Comment: Are you whitelisting google maps in your config file? Also instead of pageinit or pageshow I would use [deviceready](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready) or just plain `$(document).ready(function () {});`. Keep in mind that deviceready would fire before document.ready though.

Comment: I'm whitelisting all google maps api urls and have actually whitelisted * as well just to be sure. What I dont understand is why oit works on one android phone but not a new one?